# Argument type 'TupleEnumerableComparer<System.Tuple<int[],int[]>>' is not assignable to parameter type 'IEqualityComparer<System.Tuple<int[],int[]>>'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, lambda

I have a class as following:

```
public class TupleEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> source, Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> target)
    {
        var valuesInSource = source?.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.GetValue(source));
        
        var valuesInTarget = target?.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.GetValue(source));

        return valuesInSource != null && valuesInTarget != null &&
               valuesInSource.IsEqual(valuesInTarget, sensitiveOrdinalComparision: false);
    }
    
    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Item1, obj.Item2);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it on my list as:

```
var distinctValues = new[]
{
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3}),
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {2, 3}, new[] {5}),
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3})
}.Distinct<Tuple<int[], int[]>>(new TupleEnumerableComparer<Tuple<int[], int[]>>());
```

I get the error "Argument type 'TupleEnumerableComparer<System.Tuple<int[],int[]>>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.Tuple<int[],int[]>>'". What did I do wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: note that `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>` is not the same as `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T[], T[]>>` (which is what compiler tries to tell you)... Also please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code (I've edited and rolled back post to show roughly what code would be minimal repro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you implemented an `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>` and you assigned `Tuple<int[], int[]>` as generic.

This will lead to this Comparer: `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<IEnumerable<Tuple<int[], int[]>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<int[], int[]>>>>`

I'm pretty sure this is not what you exptected.

Try to create the comparer like:

```
public class TupleEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>>
    where T : IEnumerable
```

Create an Instance using `new TupleEnumerableComparer<int[]>()`.

But I've no Idea how to properly compare those values. Your specified implementation has a bug because the `valuesInTarget` uses `source` to retrieve the values. Another problem is that an `sensitiveOrdinalComparision` doesn't make sense to me because for that comparer no `string` is involved.

I hope that helps you to find the correct implementation even it is not the whole solution.

Maybe you can try this implementation for Equals:

```
public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> left, Tuple<T, T> right)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    if (left is null || right is null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return left.Item1.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(right.Item1.Cast<object>()) &&
           left.Item2.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(right.Item2.Cast<object>())
}
```

This is not tested and I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. That indeed did solve the issue. Just out of curiosity, may I ask why I also get the error when I create the comparer as 
```class TupleEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>``` but assign 'int' as generic. 
For example, new TupleEnumerableComparer<int>().

Comment: @hjhk19 You get this error because an `IEnumerable<T>` is not an `T[]` and you try to assign that. You can change your definition to `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T[]>, T[]>>` what should work. The downside of this is that if you need a comparer for `List<T>` instead of `T[]` you've to implement a new comparer. If you restrict the generic to `where T : IEnumerable` you're able to assign all types that implement `IEnumerable` to the generic. The only downside of this is that you have to specify the collection type to the generic. But you can use `int[]` or `List<int>` as you wish.